# Problema en la devolución de un procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure

Abro pregunta para ver si alguno puede solucionarme el problema porque ya no sé qué puede ser.
He creado un **Procedimiento almacenado** al que le paso **2 valores, 1 string y un int**. Ambos son utilizados en el procedimiento almacenado para saber si ese ID se puede "borrar" (en realidad es un borrado lógico) porque no tiene ninguna relación con nada.

El problema es que si ejecuto el Procedimiento en BBDD con datos de ejemplos, los resultados son correctos. **0** = se puede borrar, **-1** = la tabla no existe, **X** = Aparece en X tablas.
El problema es que cuando llamo al Procedimiento desde **C#, siempre** me devuelve -1.

Les adjunto el Procedimiento debajo:

```
USE [CTHA_NET_V34]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[pa_ExisteIDcomoFK]    Script Date: 08/11/2021 11:20:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_ExisteIDcomoFK] 
        @NombreTabla varchar(150),
        @valorID int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @nCuantos int;
DECLARE @sentenSQL nvarchar(max);
declare @nomTabla nvarchar(200), @nomCampo nvarchar(200), @ParmDefinition nvarchar(100);
SET @ParmDefinition = '@nCuantos int OUTPUT';

set @nCuantos = 0;

if  OBJECT_ID(@NombreTabla, 'U') IS NULL
    return -1

DECLARE curRelaciones CURSOR FOR  
SELECT tab1.name AS [tabla],
    col1.name AS [columna]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
where tab2.name = @NombreTabla
and col2.name = 'ID';


OPEN curRelaciones;
FETCH NEXT FROM curRelaciones INTO @nomTabla, @nomCampo;  
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    set  @sentenSQL = 'SET @nCuantos = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @nomTabla  + ' WHERE fbor is null AND ' + rtrim(ltrim(@nomCampo)) +
    ' = ' + ltrim(rtrim(cast(@valorID as varchar(50)))) + ')' ;  

   EXEC sp_executesql @sentenSQL, @ParmDefinition,@nCuantos=@nCuantos OUTPUT;
    
   if @nCuantos>0
        break;

   FETCH NEXT FROM curRelaciones INTO @nomTabla, @nomCampo;  
END  

CLOSE curRelaciones;  
DEALLOCATE curRelaciones; 

return @ncuantos ;

END
```

El codigo de C# es este, el que llama a la BBDD

```
public int ComprobarIDABorrar(string NombreTabla, int IDBorrar)
        {
            try
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NombreTabla) || IDBorrar == 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                int Valor = Context.pa_ExisteIDcomoFK(NombreTabla, IDBorrar);
                return Valor;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Si en la BBDD te funciona y en el codigo en C# no te funciona, deberias poner el código en C# porque probablemente allí esté el fallo.

Comment: @Marc Añadir que he debugueado el código y no entra por el menos IF en ninguna prueba

Comment: ¿Has revisado que el nombre de la tabla no tenga espacios al inicio o algún caracter extraño? Por otro lado, este procedimiento me huele medio mal. El código no hace exactamente lo que describes y estás haciendo una validación que ya tienes en tu diseño de base de datos. Eso, sin contar los problemas que puedas tener en caso de que haya una tabla o columna con algún nombre con caracteres especiales.

Comment: @LuisCazares Las tablas tienen todas nombres normales sin caracteres ni nada, y el procedimiento hace exactamente lo que comento. Busca en las tablas relacionadas que tiene esa tabla si existe algun registro con el ID que le pasamos. Te lo puedo confirmar porque desde la BBDD me devuelve valores siempre correctos.

Comment: Me refería al valor que pasas desde C#. Si pasas un valor que incluyó algún caracter que no coincida con el nombre exacto de la tabla.

Comment: Nono, los valores son exactamente los mismos que con los que pruebo en la BBDD.
Ya no se que probar ni donde puede estar el fallo

Answer (score 0):

creo que deberías hacer caso a lo que te comento Marc, si es que funciona en la BD y no en C# debes revisar que error te trae.

Te sugiero utilizar esto en tu CATCH, te dará mas detalle del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o intenta con algo parecido a esto perdon si no esta bien codificado es que utilizo ef core.

```
using (var command = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "dbo.pa_ExisteIDcomoFK";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreTabla", NombreTabla);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valorID", IDBorrar);
    ctx.Database.OpenConnection();

    var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (dataReader.Read())
    {
        int Valor = dataReader.GetInt16(dataReader.GetOrdinal("ncuantos"));
        return Valor;
    }
}
```

en ultima instancia puedes utilizar ADO.NET

Saludos.

Comment: El problema es que no me da error al uso.
El problema es que me devuelve siempre como resultado -1. No hay ninguna exception para revisar

Comment: Frank, gracias por aportar al sitio. Solo comentarte que es siempre preferido ( si no obligatorio) que copies y pegues el código en lugar de poner una captura de imagen. En este caso, si el autor de la pregunta quisiera utilizar el codigo que pones en tu respuesta, tendría que teclearlo, cuando si estuviera como texto solo tendría que copiar y pegar.

Comment: Hola Pikoh, soy nuevo en stackoverflow  eh intentado pero me sale error al tratar de registrarlo y no se puede guardar por eso mejor lo hago como imagen pero intentare algo a ver si funciona.

Comment: Frank estupendo. Si necesitas ayuda con cualquier cosa, los moderadores estamos para ayudarte :)

Comment: Genial Gracias...

Comment: Hola amigo, quizás deberías mostrar que valores mandas al método en C# 
======> ComprobarIDABorrar("",0)

Comment: @VidalLp Los valores que le mando desde C# son los mismos que uso en las pruebas desde BBDD
ComprobarIDABorrar("AGENCIASTRANSPORTE", 2)
Ese es un ejemplo de llamada que en BBDD me devuelve un 2 y en C# un -1